# Building shared ParMETIS-4.0.3

Tags: c++, build, shared-libraries, metis

How can I build a dynamic version of ParMETIS?
I compiled a shared version of METIS but when I try to compile shared ParMETIS by linking it to libmetis.so (added its path in the make file, see my makefile options below) the compilation fails because ParMETIS tries to link to libmetis.a. How can I force it to link with libmetis.so? 
I compiled the static version with no problem.
Thank you for your help

## Configuration options.

gdb        = not-set

assert     = not-set

assert2    = not-set

debug      = not-set

openmp     = not-set
prefix     = not-set

gklib_path = not-set

metis_path = ~/bin/metis-5.0

shared     = 1

cc         = mpicc

cxx        = mpicxx

Answer (score 5):

I know this comes a bit late, but I just faced the same problem.
In the file `CMakeLists.txt`, right at the root of your parmetis directory, in the section starting with:
`if(SHARED)`

you should add:
`set(METIS_LIBRARY_TYPE SHARED)`

right after the equivalent option for PARMETIS.

Hope it helps someone else, since you probably worked around the issue already.